# Json Helper Class in Razor Pages Project

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

I created a simple project and I can't seem to access the Json Helper class that I see through a bunch of sample projects. For example, I'm trying to use the Telerik dropdown sample and in the code below, I get the error:

> The name Json does not exist in the current context.

(same thing goes for JsonRequestBehavior)  What am I missing?  I've done a search in nuget for `System.Web.Helpers`, but I can't add the reference because the project is targeted for ASP.NET Core 2.0 while the assembly was restored using .NET 4.6.1.  What is my alternative?

```
public JsonResult RemoteDataSource_GetProducts(string text)
    {
        var northwind = new SampleEntities();
        var products = northwind.Products.Select(product => new ProductViewModel
        {
            ProductID = product.ProductID,
            ProductName = product.ProductName,
            UnitPrice = product.UnitPrice ?? 0,
            UnitsInStock = product.UnitsInStock ?? 0,
            UnitsOnOrder = product.UnitsOnOrder ?? 0,
            Discontinued = product.Discontinued
        });

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
        {
            products = products.Where(p => p.ProductName.Contains(text));
        }

        return Json(products, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Json(JsonResult) is a class and JsonRequestBehavior is an enum that lives within System.Web.Mvc in ASP.NET Framework. In ASP.NET Core, Json(JsonResult) lives within Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.

You should be just fine with,

```
return Json(products);
```